# WebView, Baixar Imagem

Tags: java, android, webview

Tenho um código simples de Webview e gostaria que ao clicar nas imagens do site, baixar elas perguntando ou baixando direto e mandando uma mensagem como "imagem salva"

Obs 1: Usei um tumblr pra fazer os testes
Obs 2: Gostaria de simplificar o código ao máximo pois ainda sou novato no ramo de desenvolvimento mobile

Segue o código...

```
package com.tumblr.k3rn3l.wallpapers;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide(); //Oculta a Barra Azul
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        view.loadUrl("http://k3rn3l.tumblr.com");
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Mas qual é a dúvida? Você não começou a resolver o problema ainda. Tem dúvida no algoritmo? Tem dúvida de como capturar um evento? Como salvar arquivos? Como exibir diálogos?

Comment: Levando em consideração que a imagem pode estar com uma div sobreposta ou estar em um `background-image`, pode ser que não seja possivel baixar qualquer imagem.

Comment: Sim, tenho dúvida no algoritmo, tentei implementar alguns que achei na internet mas não consegui, a imagem vai estar em uma galeria do wordpress, pelo navegador consigo salvar pressionando a imagem e clicando em "baixar imagem", gostaria de fazer o mesmo mas pelo webview